# QGIS doesn't show certain folders and files in browse mode

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, windows, qgis-browser, windows-11

I am very new to QGIS and want to import a .csv file containing coordinate data of cities into my current project so the cities will be displayed as point features. This photo shows the folder my file is in in Windows Explorer.

[image: Blue underlined is the folder my file is in.]

In QGIS, I tried Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer, but when browsing for the file I want to import, it doesn't show up. In fact, the folder in which the file is stored doesn't show up at all either.

[image: The folder isn't showing up in QGIS browse mode.]

I also tried the same method described above to add an old .csv file with coordinates. I had edited that file beforehand, so in Windows Explorer, this file shows up as being updated today. However, when browsing for this file with QGIS, the updated version from today isn't showing up - only the old version from over a year ago.

I tried closing QGIS and opening the project again, just in case updates made to files while a project is open can only be displayed after closing and reopening the project (this has worked in ArcGIS before), but this issue still exists.

How do I get QGIS to display all of my folders and files? I am using Windows 11 and QGIS
3.32.3.

Comment: When you right click on an object in the QGIS browser you have the possibility to hide (and unhide) item, check that your folder has not been hidden by error

Comment: They are not the same folder. `documents` vs `dokumente`. Note that if you have re-mapped the `my documents` folder to a new location in Windows, the original folder remains at its original location and so you are still able to save/load files from there. Some applications are better than other for getting the real path vs the default path.